# Is it possible to use pandoc from google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'd like to generate some reports from my python webapp - I set it up locally via PyPandoc.

However, I can't find PyPandoc on the list of available libraries. I tried vendoring it into my libs folder and using pypandoc's `pypandoc.pandoc_download` to download the `pandoc` binary, but that only works for 64-bit processors apparently.

Is there a way to request 64-bit environment? Or some way to get `pandoc` installed on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

In a standard environment GAE app you neet to meet the python sandbox restrictions, one of which is using pure python code, which `pandoc` doesn't meet. From [Pure Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Pure_Python):

> All code for the Python runtime environment must be pure Python, and
>   not include any C extensions or other code that must be compiled.

You *might* be able to use it in a [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) GAE app, eventually using a [custom environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/), but I'm not 100% sure - I didn't use it yet.